# Does JavaScript event delegation matter on the Window?

Tags: javascript, performance, dom-events

Is there a performance reason why you should avoid binding multiple handlers to a `Window` event and instead, use your own delegation scheme?

Event delegation makes obvious sense for eliminating the overhead of adding / removing multiple handlers where DOM elements are added and removed dynamically, but this doesn't seem like it should affect global events at all.

If you think of how you might create your own event delegation scheme on the window (create a map of event name -> list of handlers and manage accordingly), it probably looks a lot like what the browser is doing with the handlers internally anyways. Moreover, the browsers, being implemented in lower level languages, can be probably be much more efficient from a speed and memory perspective.

However, being the DOM, I know there could be some esoteric implementation detail that makes it somehow very inefficient to add or remove your own handlers, so I'm asking this to see if anyone knows if this is the case.

If this doesn't get any traction, I'll see if I can do some testing and figure it out myself.

Comment: Honestly, you should do the testing first, then ask the question. But you are correct that the browser knows a lot more than you do about its own inner workings, and that of the DOM, to make intelligent decisions about memory management.

Comment: FYI, I believe jQuery uses the technique of binding a single handler to the DOM and managing the specific handlers internally. So its designers thought this was a better way to do it.

Comment: it doesn't matter one way or the other; the runtime CPU costs for invoking such events is basically nil, as is even user-land filtering/dispatching. One might desire consistency, and to me, that would be a bigger factor than performance in picking a pattern, like with jQuery for example.

Comment: Curious why I should have done the testing first? I put in a good faith effort to see if this question had already been asked, before posting it. Since it hadn't been asked or answered, I thought that a public discussion might be useful on the topic since there are many cases where developers might encounter this trade-off. I'm thinking specifically about resize, scroll, media query events, etc.

Comment: But they may have done it this way to make the API easier. It can easily unbind its own events, and return a list of event handlers, etc.

Comment: delegation is harder (for devs) to interpret on unfamiliar systems, requiring deeper digging. Dev tools has gotten better about it, but a few years back, it was hard AF to figure out exactly what handler was intercepting a given click if you just had a big glob of minified code.

Comment: The first section header of [ask] is "Search, and research". You got the search part down (thanks for that), but the research is where the question may not be as great as it could be. Asking broad questions like "Does event delegation matter on the Window?" means that you have an obligation to narrow the focus of your question to what part of event delegation may or may not matter. You done part of that -- performance. But performance is a huge topic; many books have been written about performance of software. If you do the testing and find something interesting, that would be a good topic.

Comment: Event delegation is used to listen for events on multiple elements. Since there is only a single window object, it makes no sense to try applying it here - there's nothing an event could be delegated to.